# Power Apps Customized List Form Resized Itself to Upper Left Hand Corner

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-forms

App type:  Customized Form/SharePoint Integrated Form

Issue:  The screen or form of a published SharePoint Online customized list form shrunk to the upper left hand corner.

Seeking help on:  How do I revert the form or screen to its original size?

Background:  I did not make any changes to the form.  The live published version is the most current - from August 2021.  Today 1) I opened the form in Power Apps, 2) visually verified a formula and 3) closed Power Apps without saving changes or publishing changes.  10 minutes after closing Power Apps I accessed the SharePoint list in Chrome and clicked an item to view its customized form.  The screen or form was shrunk to the upper-left hand corner.  How do I resolve the shrunken size?
[image]

Comment: What is the formula or formulae you are using?

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I didn't save or publish any changes to data sources, layers or settings so I’m not sure what happened.  The cause was not identified so my resolution was to re-publish the last working version and update it to include changes lost in the corrupted version.  

I posted in another forum and v-bofeng-msft told me to try the below steps.  I can’t say if they work or not; I’d already published over the corrupted form version when the suggestion was delivered.  Hope their steps work for someone else!
1. Adjust the web page zoom to 100%
2. Refresh the webpage(Press F5)